# Automate a report from SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint, office365

I am new to SharePoint online I need a help to create a report on SharePoint list which need to capture new data from a list on daily basis and send to a person.
The report format is in excel/ any other in Office 365

Answer (score 0):

You could export SharePoint list data to csv file by PowerShell with CSOM.

http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/03/export-list-items-to-csv-in-sharepoint-online-using-powershell.html

Then, send reminder email to user.

http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/11/sharepoint-online-powershell-to-send-email.html

Run PowerShell script as windows task scheduler daily.

https://blog.netwrix.com/2018/07/03/how-to-automate-powershell-scripts-with-task-scheduler/